# Using JAX-WS, how do I have multiple ports inside one wsdl?

Tags: web-services, wsdl, jax-ws, wsgen

I would like to define 5 classes with an @WebService annotation on them and use wsgen to create a single wsdl for all of them.  Each class would be its own port.  I've been reading the wsgen documentation and this doesn't seem possible.  But, when I look at the wsdl spec, it appears to be possible.  http://www.w3.org/TR/wsdl#_ports  Does anyone know how to do this with wsgen?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with wsgen, however... as far as I know, you can have only one class fronting a webservice.  However, you can define multiple operations, with each operation being a distinct method in your class.  Maybe you can do something like this:

1. Define your 5 classes as normal
2. Define a 'fronting' class with a separate method that calls into each of your original 5 classes.
3. Run your 'fronting' class through `wsgen` to create a WSDL with 5 separate operations (one for each class)

As a side note, it's generally better to define webservices top-down rather than bottom-up. Create the WSDL first, and then use something like `wsdl2java` to create the java skeleton.